# i want to draw a line a between two gps coordinates on Google maps (current and server corordinates)?

Tags: android, google-maps

i am working on an location Tracking application , i want to draw line between two latitude and longitude , current and coordinates fetch from server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside you overridden method.

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polylineOptions
                .add(new LatLng(Currentlati, Currentlongi))
                .add(new LatLng(latiFromServer,longiFromServer));
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
}
```